# Makefile is not using my variables and rules ( namely a compiler and flags to it )

Tags: c++, makefile

I seem to be having an issue getting my makefile to build my C++ file correctly. My makefile code is below; the file I am trying to compile is named "avl.cc" (which is working and compiles properly).

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-g -O2
PROGS=avl

all: $(PROGS)

$@:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $@.cc

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm $(PROGS)
```

However, when I enter the command `make` or `make all`, I get

```
c++     avl.cc   -o avl
```

And the debugging symbols I want from the `-g` flag don't come up. A similar makefile (only changing the `PROGS` variable) worked for a similar project, so I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Run `make -p`. You need `CXX=g++` and `CXXFLAGS= -Wall -g -O2`; also use `remake` as `remake -x` and (if your GNU `make` is recent enough) `make --trace`

Comment: What are you expecting `$@:` as a target to be doing for you? Because whatever you are expecting it isn't doing that. That variable doesn't exist at that point in make processing.

Answer (score 3):

From [Makefile documentation about automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html):

> It’s very important that you recognize the limited scope in which
> automatic variable values are available: they only have values within
> the recipe. In particular, you cannot use them anywhere within the
> target list of a rule; they have no value there and will expand to the
> empty string.

This means you cannot use `$@` as a rule, which means the default c++ compilation rule of Makefile is used, and since you did not use the correct variable names for c++ compilation, they are also ignored.

You can replace `CC` by `CXX` and `CFLAGS` by `CXXFLAGS` to work with c++.

Comment: The only actually correct answer here!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same question but a much different source of the problem. There were typos and/or misnamed files in my makefile. Make found no rules for such files but tried to compile targets with the c++ compiler. This made the process seem like it  was ignoring my rules and imposing its own, switching compilers since I needed g++. Finally I tried using the -r option, and then the resulting different error messages allowed me to figure out what was really wrong. Below is the entry from the make man page for option -r.

```
   -r, --no-builtin-rules
        Eliminate use of the built-in implicit rules.  Also clear out the default 
list of suffixes for suffix rules.
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is queried by the question asked, not the solution. Plus the first line of my answer explicitly states: "same question but a much different source of the problem".      Example: My car isn't starting, Why?      The details suggest a dead battery. The chosen answer points this out.     Still helpful to give an instance where loose cable was the problem.

Comment: Also a big thank you to everyone down voting because they misunderstand the purpose of my answer. But that's what you get for trying to be helpful.

Comment: I appreciate that but in my experience disabling built in rules is almost never the answer. but in this case you are correct it would have illuminated the problem so i'm changing my vote. thank you for the well spoken analogy. that aside your question is not equivalent to this question then. the question is the whole question not just the title bar :-) but i think you were over penalized for a helpful suggestion

Comment: that said you should open a separate question with your example as the problem and answer it yourself I know I would upvote both of those, as examples such as yours would be great for teaching folks how to solve problems themselves

Comment: to enhance my point. My car isn't starting is not a valid question on stack overflow (nor would it be on a car-overflow etc.) the question is more than the title. it is the entire minimally reproduceable question.  A common misconception is that any question with a title that sounds relevant to your problem extends to cover your problem as well, which is why often times we change these titles.  My car doesn't start could go anywhere. You could be using the wrong key. Your battery could be unplugged. Listing every possible solution would be unsearchable within a single question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a target for `avl`, so make uses a default rule.

Try changing the makefile to this:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-g -O2
PROGS=avl

all: $(PROGS)

$(PROGS):
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $@.cc

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm $(PROGS)
```

Comment: dont use CC for C++/g++ use CXX, and then use CXXFLAGS instead.  still unclear why standard rules are not sufficient aside from setting CXXFLAGS